# SEO for partial pages in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, seo

Lets say I have some pages which are developed in ASP.Net MVC. And the header and footer are same for all the pages..Now there is two approaches which I am thing about..

1. Make a _Layout page for all the pages so that no need to repeat header and footer.
2. Make all of the pages separately without _Layout page.

If I use 2nd approach definitely I am not taking advantage of MVC framework.

My question is If take 1st approach will it effect my site SEO as The SEO is the most important part of this application? Will it consider all the pages separate in case of SEO as pages will render on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't care how you form the page on the server side, because they don't know how :) The crawler only sees the end result as a normal user.

SEO is about other things. MVC is basically good for SEO because of its URLs .."/Cats/RedCat". Of course there are many other things that contribute in SEO, you need to check it out. But diffidently using a layout is not related.